# $\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^ndx$ consists of a sum of rational numbers whose denominators are less than $2n+1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, elementary-number-theory, definite-integrals

While reading "Problems in Algebraic Number Theory" by Ram Murty I am stuck at one point where it is written that $\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^ndx$ consists of a sum of rational numbers whose denominators are less than $2n+1$.

I am not getting why that is true. Please help.

Comment: Beta function/Eulerian integral of the second kind...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the binomial theorem
$$ x^n(1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k x^{n+k} $$
and by integrating both sides over $(0,1)$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}}{\color{red}{n+k+1}} $$
By integration by parts, the LHS equals $B(n+1,n+1)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)^2}{\Gamma(2n+2)} = \frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}$.